# How to toggle between DIVs with bound data in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

So the problem I'm facing is that I have a template that fetches data from a Realtime Firebase Database and at the same time the user can import more data through an `input` element. I'm using Vue.js and I need the data to be bound to each other.

Here is my template:

```html
    <template>
        <ul>
          <li>
             <input type="text" v-model="email" v-on:keyup.enter="addData()"/>
             <img @click="addData()" src="@/assets/Plus.png" />
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="(item, key) in emails" :key="key">
            <div>
              <p>{{ item.data }}</p>
              <img @click="deleteDataByKey(key)" src="@/assets/Delete.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="first">
              <input type="text" v-model="comment[key]" v-on:keyup.enter="addComment(key, comment[key])"/>
              <img @click="addComment(key, comment[key])" src="@/assets/Plus.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="second">
              <p>{{ comment[key] }}</p>
              <img @click="deleteCommentByKey(key)" src="@/assets/Delete.png" />
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
</template>
```

Now what is happening is that I want to show `<div class="first">` when there is no comment and when there is one, `<div class="second">` should be shown while hiding the first one.

I tried using `v-if="comment[key]"` but it will toggle the divs straight away.
I also tried to `v-model.lazy` which seems to be working but then the method to update the db is not called.
I tried using pure JS in the method to change the HTML but it doesn't seem to be working as well.

These are my methods and data:

```js
    data() {
      return {
        emailList: [],
        email: "",
        comment: []
      };
    },
    addData() {
       db.ref("emailItems").push({
         data: data
       });
       this.email = "";
       this.fetchData();
    },

    deleteDataByKey(key) {
      db.ref("emailItems"+key).remove();
      this.fetchData();
    },

    addComment(key, comment) {
      db.ref(`emailItems/${key}/comment`).set(comment);
    },

    deleteCommentByKey(key){
      db.ref("comment/"+key).remove();
      this.fetchData();
    },
    
    fetchData() {
     db.ref("emailItems")
        .once("value")
        .then(snapshot => {
          this.emailList = snapshot.val().emailItems;
        });
    }
```

And the db structure looks like this

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should build more on the (arguably) biggest features of **Vue**, namely: reactivity & components.

Break down the logic a bit more, until you arrive at elements that do only one thing - those elements can be your components. Then build up the business logic from those atomic components.

```js
Vue.component('NewEmail', {
  data() {
    return {
      email: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleKeyup() {
      this.$emit("add-email", {
        email: this.email,
        comment: null
      })
      this.email = null
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <label>
        NEW EMAIL: <input
          type="email"
          placeholder="Type in an email"
          v-model="email"
          @keyup.enter="handleKeyup"
        />
      </label>
    </div>
  `
})

Vue.component('SingleEmailRow', {
  props: {
    email: {
      type: Object,
      default: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleDeleteClick() {
      this.$emit('remove-email', this.email)
    },
  },
  template: `
    <li
      class="d-flex"
    >
      <div>
        {{ email.email }}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button
          @click="handleDeleteClick"
        >
          X
        </button>
      </div>
      <component
        :is="email.comment ? 'HasEmailComment' : 'NoEmailComment'"
        :email="email"
        v-on="$listeners"
      ></component>
    </li>
  `
})

Vue.component('HasEmailComment', {
  props: {
    email: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleUpdateComment() {
      this.$emit('update:comment', { ...this.email,
        comment: null
      })
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div
      class="d-flex"
    >
      <div>
        {{ email.comment }}
      </div>
      <button
        title="Remove comment"
        @click="handleUpdateComment"
      >
        -
      </button>
    </div>
  `
})

Vue.component('NoEmailComment', {
  props: {
    email: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      comment: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleUpdateComment() {
      this.$emit('update:comment', { ...this.email,
        comment: this.comment
      })
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div
      class="d-flex"
    >
      <div>
        <input
          v-model="comment"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Write a comment"
        />
      </div>
      <button
        title="Add comment"
        @click="handleUpdateComment"
      >
        +
      </button>
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      emailList: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleAddEmail(newEmail) {
      if (!this.emailList.find(({
          email
        }) => email === newEmail.email)) {
        this.emailList.push(newEmail)
      }
    },
    handleRemoveEmail(toRemove) {
      this.emailList = this.emailList.filter(({
        email
      }) => {
        return email !== toRemove.email
      })
    },
    handleUpdateComment(newEmail) {
      this.emailList = this.emailList.map(email => {
        if (email.email === newEmail.email) {
          return newEmail
        } else {
          return email
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <new-email @add-email="handleAddEmail"></new-email>
  <ul v-for="(email, i) in emailList" :key="i">
    <single-email-row :email="email" @remove-email="handleRemoveEmail" @update:comment="handleUpdateComment"></single-email-row>
  </ul>
</div>
```

OK, the `comment` handling in `SingleEmailRow` could be put to its separate component (based on my thoughts above).

The main points in the snippet above are:

- there's only one original data source (`emailList` in the root component) that is passed down as `props` where needed, and all the other components & functions just manipulate THAT list via `events` (reactivity is great!)
- because all the components are based on one central data source, they just have to work with the item they get as `props`. (Ok, they have some internal state, but hey - this is only a snippet! :) )
- the two components have only one responsibility:

  - `NewEmail`: to add an item to the central `emailList`
  - `SingleEmailRow`: to manage the data in ONE email item

**I hope this helps you a bit to reach a solution for your problem.**

### EDIT: UPDATING SNIPPET

I had to update the snippet, because I wasn't satisfied with it.

Modifications:

- adding two new components: `HasEmailComment`, `NoEmailComment`
- updated `SingleEmailRow` with the two new components

Now, all the components have only one task to do.

Comment: Your solution is working and the info you provided helped me a lot hence I'm accepting it as the correct answer. I was looking though more of  a quick fix if there could be one. Now I need to rearrange the whole structure ..

Comment: FYI: I fixed it in another way. Basically I rendered the data coming from the db in the div rather than binding straight away the data from the input field. Thank you very much for your effort @gergely

Comment: @MakisMilas thanks for the response! I'm glad that I could help and that you found a solution!